# jQuery .animate() not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, colors

I am designing a website and for effects I came across the below set of jquery code for achieve text color change with animation. But it doesn't work and I am not sure what is wrong.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FMTDp/14/)

Below is the code that I'm currently experiencing the issue with:

**jQuery:**

```
$('.list-5 li a').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ color: '#fff' })
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ color: '#0e1b23' })
})
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="list-5">
    <ul>
     <li>
       <a href="#">Hello world</a> 
     </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: What does _"But it's not works"_ mean?

Comment: @gdoron: When we hover the color changes to another color

Comment: @krish - When using hex codes for setting colors you must either use the 3-character hex code or 6-character.  There is not a 4-character implementation.

Comment: As a side note, in JavaScript, for reasons I won't labour over here, it's better to put opening braces on the same line, not on the next.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`#FFFF` is an invalid color. Use either `#FFF` or `#FFFFFF`.

Also, the default jQuery `.animate` does not animate colors. You'll have to use jQuery UI for that (or the [Color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color)).

- Demo using the color plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/FMTDp/13/
- Demo using jQuery UI: http://jsfiddle.net/FMTDp/15/

Answer (score 2):

**You can't animate colors!**

```
.animate({
        color: '#ffff'
    });
```

unless you add a reference to jQuery UI.

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used).

[**Working DEMO using jQuery UI**](http://jsfiddle.net/FMTDp/16/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use jQuery UI or jQuery plugin to animate color. You are also using wrong color code, use `#fff` or `#ffffff`.

From [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> For example, width, height, or left can be animated but
>   background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used
>
> Note: The jQuery UI project extends the .animate() method by allowing
>   some non-numeric styles such as colors to be animated. The project
>   also includes mechanisms for specifying animations through CSS classes
>   rather than individual attributes.